# Running script (stash) prior to parallel stages being invoked

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parallel stage setup, and would like to know if it's possible to run a script prior to the nested stages, so something like this:

```
stage('E2E-PR-CYPRESS') {
    when {
        allOf {
            expression { 
                return fileExists("cypress.json") 
            }
            branch "PR-*"
        }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            stash name: 'cypress-dir', includes: 'cypress/**/*'
        }
    }
    parallel {
        stage('Cypress Tests 1') {
            agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
            options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
            steps {
                runE2eTests()
            }
        }
        stage('Cypress Tests 2') {
            agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
            options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
            steps {
                runE2eTests()
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            e2eAfterCypressRun(this, true)
        }
    }
}
```

I know the above is wrong, I get the error `Only one of "matrix", "parallel", "stages", or "steps" allowed for stage "E2E-PR-CYPRESS"`

I already have the stash script in a setup stage at the beginning of my pipeline, but I'd like to be able to restart from this stage above on Jenkins, and so need the stash part in this stage as the parallel stages need to unstash the contents.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated Answer:

After playing a bit with the [Restart from a Stage](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/) option there is seems to be a nice feature designed exactly for your needs called *Preserving `stash`es for Use with Restarted Stages*:

> Normally, when you run the stash step in your Pipeline, the resulting
> stash of artifacts is cleared when the Pipeline completes, regardless
> of the result of the Pipeline. Since stash artifacts aren’t accessible
> outside of the Pipeline run that created them, this has not created
> any limitations on usage. But with Declarative stage restarting, you
> may want to be able to unstash artifacts from a stage which ran before
> the stage you’re restarting from.
>
> To enable this, there is a job property that allows you to configure a
> maximum number of completed runs whose stash artifacts should be
> preserved for reuse in a restarted run. You can specify anywhere from
> 1 to 50 as the number of runs to preserve.
>
> This job property can be configured in your Declarative Pipeline’s options section, as below:
>
> ```
> options {
>    preserveStashes() 
>    // or
>    preserveStashes(buildCount: 5) 
> }
> ```

This built in feature is exactly what you need to solve your issue without any special modifications to your code, as it will allow you to rerun the pipeline from any stage and still use the existing file that were previously stashed.

### Original Answer:

You can actually achieve this quite simply using the scripted syntax for the `parallel` command, and it will also allow you to avoid the duplicate code in the parallel stages.

> parallel: Execute in parallel
> Takes a map from branch names to closures and an optional argument failFast which will terminate all branches upon a failure in any other branch:
>
> ```
> parallel firstBranch: {
>      // do something
>  }, secondBranch: {
>      // do something else
>  },
>  failFast: true|false
> ```

In your case it can look like:

```groovy
stage('E2E-PR-CYPRESS') {
    when {
        allOf {
            expression {
                return fileExists("cypress.json")
            }
            branch "PR-*"
        }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            stash name: 'cypress-dir', includes: 'cypress/**/*'

            // Define the parallel execution stages
            def stages = ['Cypress Tests 1', 'Cypress Tests 2']

            // Create the parallel executions and run them
            parallel stages.collectEntries {
                ["Running ${it}": {
                    node('aws_micro_slave_e2e') {
                        skipDefaultCheckout()
                        runE2eTests()
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            e2eAfterCypressRun(this, true)
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can easily add more parallel steps by updating the `stages` list, or even receive it as an input parameter. In addition you can create the parallel executions by different labels or tests suits, instead of the stage name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Prepare` stage at the top like this:

```
 stages{
    stage('Preperation'){
        when {
            allOf {
                expression { 
                    return fileExists("cypress.json") 
                }
                branch "PR-*"
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                stash name: 'cypress-dir', includes: 'cypress/**/*'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('E2E-PR-CYPRESS') {
        parallel {
            stage('Cypress Tests 1') {
                agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
                options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
                steps {
                    runE2eTests()
                }
            }
            stage('Cypress Tests 2') {
                agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
                options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
                steps {
                    runE2eTests()
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
post {
    always {
        e2eAfterCypressRun(this, true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what he already has today... This will not allow him to restart the execution form the E2E-PR-CYPRESS stage as he requested.

Comment: If the stash is inside the "stage" there is no point to it, since restarting from the stage is going to first do the stash and then unstash whatever it just stashed. But where are files for stashing supposed to come from, all the previous stages where files are most likely generated were skipped? IMO, this solution is valid.

Comment: Read the question again. He already has a **setup** stage with the stash step but he wants something else. Therefore while this is a good valid solution for the general case it is not relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

## An out of the box concept

**Propose splitting the job into 2 parts taking the following into consideration:**

- Currently use an EC2 plugin, as the current agents are EC2
- Running the parallel stages with the same stashed content ready to unstash

**Create jenkins pipeline job 1:**

- This job will checkout the workspace with any type of agent
- Create a packer json to create a customised AMI for the EC2
- The customised AMI will stash the contents and move to a directory that will appear on the EC2 when the agent is built
- Output the AMI ID, run a groovy job to update the EC2 plugin AMI ID with the customised AMI ID to temporarily set the AMI in memory on Jenkins

```
    pipeline {
      agent {
        docker { 
        test-container
        }
      }
      options {
        buildDiscarder(
          logRotator(
            numToKeepStr: '10',
            artifactNumToKeepStr: '10'
          )
        )
        ansiColor('xterm')
        gitConnection("git")
      }
      stages {
        stage('Run Stash Cypress Functional Test') {
          steps {
            dir('functional-test') {
              // develop branch is canary build, all other branches are stable builds 
              script {
                sh """
                  # script to stash cypress tests 
                """
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Functional Test AMI Build') {
          steps {
            dir('functional-test/packer') {
              withAWS(role: 'PackerBuild', roleAccount: '123456789012', roleSessionName: 'Jenkins-Workflow-FunctionalTest-Packer') {
                script {
                  sh """
                    # packer json script will require to copy contents from workspace, run the script to stash content
                    # packer json script will require to capture new AMI ID
                    # https://discuss.devopscube.com/t/how-to-get-the-ami-id-after-a-packer-build/36
                    # https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/manifest
                    packer validate FunctionalTestPacker.json
                    packer build -debug FunctionalTestPacker.json
                    # grab AMI ID and export as jenkins env variable
                  """
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('run groovy script to update AMI ID on EC2 plugin') {
          steps {
            dir(groovy job dir) {
              script {
                sh """
                    # run groovy job to update AMI on Jenkins EC2 plugin
                    # https://gist.github.com/vrivellino/97954495938e38421ba4504049fd44ea
    
                """
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Kickoff Functional Test Deploy') {
          // pipeline checkbox parameter, when ticked it will automatically kick off the functional test pipeline
          when {
            expression {params.RUN_TESTS.toBoolean()}
          }
          steps {
            script{
              env.branch = params.BRANCH
              sh """
                echo "Branch is ${branch}"
              """
            }
            build job: 'workflow/CypressFunctionaTestDeployAndRun',
              parameters: [
                string(name: 'BRANCH', value: env.branch)
              ],
            wait : false
          }
        }
      }
      post {
        always {
          cleanWs()
        }
      }
    }
```

**Create jenkins pipeline job 2:**

- This job will create the EC2 agents via the plugin from the customised AMI from pipeline job 1
- This means your agents will have the same workspace ready to unstash - so you can execute a parallel run
- Also you could move a lot of your user data script that is in the EC2 plugin as part of the customised AMI build, thus cut down the time for each EC2 agent to get ready to carry out execution

```
    pipeline {
        stages {
            stage('E2E-PR-CYPRESS') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        expression { 
                            return fileExists("cypress.json") 
                        }
                        branch "PR-*"
                    }
                }
            }
            parallel {
                stage('Cypress Tests 1') {
                    agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
                    options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
                    steps {
                        runE2eTests()
                    }
                }
                stage('Cypress Tests 2') {
                    agent { label 'aws_micro_slave_e2e' }
                    options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
                    steps {
                        runE2eTests()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                e2eAfterCypressRun(this, true)
            }
        }
    }
```